# Image garbage collection failed: unable to find data for container / . Unable to start kubernetes master

Tags: kubernetes

I have a setup kubernetes cluster with one master and 3 minions and it is working for quite some time. But recently i noticed that kubelet.log file has eaten most of the disk space. So i stopped the kubernetes service and deleted the kubelet.log file. But when i restart the kubernetes service it is not starting. I found the below error in the log

Image garbage collection failed: unable to find data for container /

Please let me know what is the issue.

Comment: Did you try deleting dead/exited containers and dangling images manually?

Comment: Yes i tried deleting the exited containers manually. I have no dead containers. is that a problem?

Comment: No not at all, my point was that it's easier to track down the issue with a clean environment. Could you edit your question and provide more information about your Operating System and the way you run your kubelet? For example which version, runtime flags, whether you run kubelet inside a container.

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue. it was not because of the garbage collection in kubernetes but because my api server was not starting up. so when i fix the issue with api server remaining components in kubernetes like controller and scheduler also started working. 
Anyway below are details of the environment.
Docker version: 1.9.1
Kubernetes version: 1.1.2
All the kubernetes components are run as containers using hyperkube

Comment: How did you solve the API server startup issue?

Comment: Our API server used ETCD for configuration store and Flannel for networking. I dont remember exactly which of those containers went down, so when i restarted the Flannel and ETCD containers, API server started working